# Prove or disprove: if $\sum a_n^2$ is a convergent series, then $\sum a_n$ also converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

By divergence test, I can only assume  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ of $a_n^2$ is $0$ and $\lim{n\rightarrow\infty}$ of an is $0$. However that doesn't prove that the sum is convergent. I'm unsure how to approach this question.

Comment: You should always consider the standard examples when trying to prove or disprove facts about series. The most standard example is the harmonic series. What happens in that case?

Comment: a better question is the reverse: if $\sum a_n$ converges, does $\sum a_n^2$ converge?

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$. Is this a familiar series?

Answer (score 1):

Be

$$(a_n)^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}$$

The infinite series does converge to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Take now

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n}$$

The infinite series diverges.

Hence: no, or better: not in general.